# Computer Monitor Limiting Bandwidth

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, display

I have a MacBook Pro, and I have an HP computer monitor that connects to the laptop using an adapter (Thunderbolt to VGA). I have noticed that when I am using the MacBook without the monitor connected, the Wi-Fi performs just fine. However, when the monitor is connected (even if only moments after the Wi-Fi is performing perfectly), the Wi-Fi goes nearly standstill, sometimes not connecting at all until I disconnect the monitor and it resumes.

I am curious if anyone else has experienced this problem, and if anyone has any possible solutions for this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: See if changing the graphics resolution that you're outputting to the monitor makes a difference.

Comment: @Spiff I just tinkered around with resolution and screen refresh rate, and am finding that the Wi-Fi connection is not too bad at all on 60 Hz as opposed to the default 70 Hz. I wonder why this would be?